# How to create bold print in TextArea?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, textarea, bold

I've research and seen many versions of this

```
JEditorPane textarea = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
listArea.setText("<b>Bold</b>");
```

Unfortunately that does not seem to work for me, I'm not sure if it can be a result of different versions of netbeans as I am new to working with it.

How to I bold certain words?

EDIT: Well there is not much to show...it is quite literally a line after a actionPerformed Button...

```
private void sortButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        JEditorPane listArea = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
        listArea.setText("<B>Adjectives</B>" + "/n"); //I've tried both upper and lower case
```

Comment: I am aware this has probably been asked one billion times

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that root of your problem is that you have declared `textarea` but changing text in `listArea`?

Could you try this code to test it?

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
JEditorPane textarea = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
//listArea.setText("<b>Bold</b>");
textarea.setText("<b>Bold</b> and normal text");
frame.add(textarea);
frame.setSize(300,300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: whoops, that must be a question error from when I added it, but its not like in my code. I'll try out what you posted.

Comment: Its really the same thing, only a different frame. It does work though , however when I delete the new Frame the only thing is left is the code I posted in my question. However with that nothing even appears and the textArea appears blank.

Comment: Without code example that I could use to reproduce your problem I won't be able to help you solve it. Please [[edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17097584/edit)] add [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @user2407152 Code included in your answer is probably correct and problem is hidden somewhere else. Please create and post short but complete code that can be used to reproduce problem.

Comment: post short? Sorry I'm not sure what that is,

Comment: It is Netbeans version 6.9.1 if it makes a difference

Comment: @user2407152 Sorry, I was AFK and will be for another 20min. By short code I meant code that is not too long, lets say 40 lines is OK. NetBeans version shouldn't matter, but since you are using it to create GUI I assume that it is hard for you to write your GUI code. Maybe lets try this way. If that is true then try to crate new project and create new simple frame with `JEditorPane` that will reproduce problem and post its code in your question. Maybe I will be able to find problem.

Answer (score 2):

Read the Swing tutorial on [Using Text Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) for working examples.

If you still have a problem the post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.